# Extract full path from executable

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string that contains an exe full path and exe name like so:

```
mainExePath = "c:\Folder1\Folder2\MyProgram.exe"
```

I want to get jus the path like so:

```
"c:\Folder1\Folder2\"
```

I have tried this:

```
string mainPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(mainExePath);
```

but this returned the same string.

How can I do this?

Comment: I am sure you didn't hardcode that path into your application? I bet you determine it using `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`...

Answer (score 6):

Use `Path.GetDirectoryName(mainExePath)`

Answer (score 4):

That would be

```
string mainPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(mainExePath);
```

This works for both paths including file names and paths only.

See the [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following one:

```
string mainPath = Directory.GetParent(mainExePath);
```

For further documentation on this, please haev a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**Update**

In order you use the `Directory` class, you have to use the `System.IO`. So please, on the sections of your source file, where you have placed the `using` statements for namespaces, please add also the below one:

```
using System.IO;
```